# CL-PPCRE Unicode Property

Tags: common-lisp, cl-ppcre

I am trying to find a solution to this simple Perl code using the CL-PPCRE Library:

```
if (/\p{Space}/){
  print "This string has some spaces\n";
}
```

I am a newbie to CL-PPCRE and tried:

```
   (scan "\\p{\\#Space}" "The String has some white spaces")
```

; I got an error saying property #/Space doesn't exists.

How can I execute an equivalent?

Answer (score 4):

The perl regexp `/\p{Space}/` matches more than just " ". cf [\p{} docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html#Properties-accessible-through-%5Cp%7B%7D-and-%5CP%7B%7D)

One approach is to just use the `\s` expression:

```
(cl-ppcre:scan "\\s" (format nil "hi~Cthere" #\return))
```

To use the whole unicode Space class:

```
(ql:quickload :cl-unicode)
(cl-ppcre:scan "\\p{Space}" (format nil "hi~Cthere" #\return))
```

See [Unicode properties](http://weitz.de/cl-ppcre/#unicode) in the CL-PPCRE docs.

Comment: I tried you code and it always produces NIL:(cl-ppcre:scan "\\p{Space}" (format t "hi~Cthere" #\return))

Comment: I tried the following but it always produces a NIL: (if(cl-ppcre:scan "\\p{Space}" "There is a space here.") (print "Success!")) ;=>NIL if (cl-ppcre:scan "\\p{Digit}" "There is a digit 411")(print "Success!") ;=>nil. {whatever} doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: note (format t …) prints to `*standard-output*`, (format nil …) writes to a new string.

Answer (score -1):

The `cl-ppcre` library does not require you (at least for space) to use any special constant.

```
(if (cl-ppcre:scan " " "alle meine entchen")
    (FORMAT T "Does have spaces~%")
    (FORMAT T "Does not have spaces~%"))
> Does have spaces

(if (cl-ppcre:scan " " "allemeineentchen")
    (FORMAT T "Does have spaces~%")
    (FORMAT T "Does not have spaces~%"))
> Does not have spaces
```

will do the trick.